# Using ConfidentialClientApplication, are we able to add a 'resource' property to the request body

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I am trying to use Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder  to configure service to service  access token management.
out of the box it works as expected. However,  I've set things up in Azure application registrations slightly different

I've got a  host/server app registration  which has some application roles configured in it.  I then intend to create multiple client app registrations and give them access to specific roles of the server application.  the concept works well in Postman and I am struggling to get it going  using ConfidentialClientApplication.

In Postman this is what it looks like [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSwu8.png)
inspecting the request in fiddler this is what I can see [fiddler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCU9t.png)

However,  when I go to configure the same  using the confidentialClientApplicationBuilder I get different results

````cs
var scopes = new List<string> { ".default"  };
var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder

    .Create("ClientId")

    .WithClientSecret("secret")

    .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tennantid"))
    .WithExtraQueryParameters("resource=api://resource")
    .Build()
    ;

 
 
var accessTokenRequest = confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes);
var accessToken = accessTokenRequest.ExecuteAsync().Result.AccessToken;
Console.WriteLine(accessToken);```
````

the resource appears as a query parameter and not as a body attribute

[ConfidentialClientApplication Fiddler Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6H7t.png)

my question is how can I configure this it  include the 'resource' setting in the payload and not as a query parameter